# Square lattice in the magnetic field; can someone please explain hopping factor Hofstadter uses?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, solid-state-physics, lattice-model, lattice-gauge-theory

If we have a square lattice in a homogenous magnetic field $\vec{B}=(0,0,B)$ and we use the Landau gauge for the magnetic potential $\vec{A}=(0,Bx,0)$; then, I have two questions:

**QUESTION $1$.** Is the given picture correct for the **direction** and **magnitude** of the magnetic potential $A$?

[image]

**QUESTION $2$.** If the answer to the first question is yes, can someone please explain why Hofstadter in his paper (a screenshot is attached) uses two different signs for the hopping factor in the $y$ direction?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QUESTION 1:
The answer is yes, you got the right picture.

**edit after comments**

The reason is simply that $\vec{A} = (0, Bx, 0)$ is a vector field (a vector
defined in each point in space, but in this case we are just interested in the lattice points). So in the points $(x=a, y)$ it is $(0, Ba, 0)$ (modulus is $Ba$ and direction is positive $y$); in the points $(x=2a, y)$ it is $(0, 2Ba, 0)$ (modulus is $2Ba$, direcion is positive $y$ again) and so on and so forth.

QUESTION 2:
The sign of the phase factor of an hopping process depends on the direction of the hopping. If a hopping event from $(x,y)$ to $(x,y+a)$ occurs with a phase factor $e^{-i\gamma x}$ then an opping event from $(x,y+a)$ to $(x,y)$ (opposite to the previous one) occurs with a fase factor $e^{+i\gamma x}$.
This guarantees that the Hamiltonian of the system is an Hermiteian operator, which should convince you about the signs.
However there is also a more formal proof that if you want I can discuss in some detail

Comment: I detailed a little bit more, let me know if it helps :) or I can be even more specific

Comment: Thank you very much; I got it. @Matteo

Comment: Another question just came to my mind: if we set the horizontal axis in the middle (the yellow one) by $y=0$ (positive $y$ above and negative $y$ below this line), then, will the direction of all $A$ below this line change downward?  Is this acceptable physically? @Matteo

Comment: I would say no, the vector potential doesn't change at all with respect to the position of the $x$ axis. However it can change with respect to the choice of the origin since it depends on the $x$ coordinate of the point, which is arbitrary. However this is not a problem because the vector potential is defined up to a gauge transformation

Comment: Sorry again, I promise that this will be my final question: according to your last comment if we set the yellow line (in the new picture at the end of the post) as $x=0$, then on this vertical line, we have $A=0$? and for all the vertical lines on the left of this line, all the $A$ have the downward direction? In other words, setting $x=0$ as the yellow line, is the new picture correct? Thank you in advance; your answer will really help me with my problem. @Matteo

Comment: Yes! It's correct :) Again, the important thing to get here is that even though $\vec{A}$ is arbitrary (since it depends on the coordinate system that you decide to use), this is not a problem since $\vec{A}$ is not a physical observable (i.e. it's not gauge invariant, technically speaking).

Comment: I am really sorry that I am back again (despite I had promised that it was my last question). I have another question: if the flux per cell is $\phi=\frac{2\pi}3$, then we will get a magnetic unit cell that contains three plaquettes; I am sure that we can consider these three plaquettes in the horizontal direction in the given picture. My question is can we consider this unit cell in the vertical direction (in the above picture) as well?     @Matteo

Comment: I am not sure I am getting your point... I would say that the "magnetic unit cell" has three plaquettes in the vertical direction and just one in the horizontal direction. This is because it is the vertical tunneling that acquires a phase in the chosen gauge.